# DynamoDB getAccumulatedConsumedCapacity on ItemCollection always returns NULL

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am running a query on the DynamoDB GlobalSecondaryIndex. Post query, I want to check how much capacity I consumed. Based on the documentation, the ItemCollection provides a method `getAccumulatedConsumedCapacity` that does exactly this. However, when I try to use this in my code, it always returns NULL.

```
private void dummyMethod(QuerySpec querySpec) {
    ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> queryOutcomes = index.query(querySpec);

    Iterator<Item> itemIterator = queryOutcomes.iterator();

    while(itemIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map<String, Object> itemAsMap = itemIterator.next().asMap();
        // do something with itemAsMap
    }

    if(queryOutcomes.getAccumulatedConsumedCapacity() == null) {
        LOGGER.error("capacity is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no problem with this piece of code. The bug was in the caller method. In order for the results to return the consumed capacity, we have to explicitly set ReturnConsumedCapacity field.

For example: `withReturnConsumedCapacity(ReturnConsumedCapacity.TOTAL);`.